# how to split ruby string with Regex?

Tags: regex, ruby

Hi I want to split this string into the following.

```
text = "In the last summer, I visited the U.S. with my friend. It was great experience. I loved an ice cream in the U.S. Welcome to U.S.A. pal!"
```

```
In the last summer, I visited the U.S. with my friend.
It was great experience.
I loved an ice cream in the U.S.
Welcome to U.S.A. pal!
```

Obviously, I can't apply `text.split(".")` nor `text.split(". ")`. So the thing is first rule is that the string will be split by `"."` with the exception of words that are abbreviated. However, I have no idea how I can do this in Ruby.

It seems that using Regex might work but I have not understood how to do this. Would you please share your idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you want to split at whitespace after a period, followed by an uppercase letter:

```
text.split(/(?<=\.)\s+(?=[[:upper:]])/)
```

The regular expression will only match the whitespace `\s+`, but ensure that it was preceded by a period using a positive lookbehind `(?<=\.)` and followed by an uppercase letter using a positive lookahead `(?=[[:upper:]])`.